# Python 3 While loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
while True:
    name = input('Enter Texture Pack Name- ')
    name_length = len(name)

    if len(name) <= 0:
        print ('You didnt write anything, try again.')

    if len(name) == 1:
        print ('Thats not enough, try again.')

    if len(name) >= 18:
        print ('Thats to much, try again.')    

    if int(name_length) >= 2:
        break

print (('Texture Pack- %s') % (name))
```

So I'm trying to make 2 limits for the names description, it being too small and it being too large. I set the break to `>= 2` so anything above the 18 max limit will break. How would I tell it to break only if the length is more than 2 but less than 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's a couple issues that I see.

Not all the code is in your `while` loop. All of the `if` statements should be in your while loop simply indent this. This is probably what it should look like:

```
while True:
    name = input("Enter Texture Pack Name- ")
    name_length = len(name)

    if name_length <= 0 or >=18:
        print("There's an error!")
        break
    else:
        print("texture pack- %s" % (name)
```

Hopefully that helps. Just so you know, the `break` must be within a loop.

Edit: Discard the top. I'm rewriting this!

```
while True:
    try:
        name = input("Enter texture pack name: ")
        name_length = int(len(name))
    if name_length <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Nothing was written!")
    elif name_length == 1:
        raise ValueError("Only one character!")
    elif name_length >= 18:
        raise ValueError("More than 18!")
    else:
        break
print ("Texture pack: %s" % (name))
```

This will keep asking for the right input until it get's it right.

Comment: Thats was just me not indenting it correctly in the example sorry about that.

Comment: Ok! That got me really confused! I'll change up my answer now with that.

Comment: This actually ended up working better for me thanks for showing me "ValueError"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
name = input('Enter Texture Pack Name- ')
while len(name) <= 2 or len(name) >= 18:
    print('Error - texture pack name length should be between 2 and 17 characters')
    name = input('Enter Texture Pack Name- ')
```

Comment: Yeah, that has to be there otherwise the `len(name)` function call will complain that `name` is not defined. Setting it to `''` also ensures enters the loop on the first evaluation of the expression.

Comment: I see an issue with that; aren't you trying to calculate the length of the texture pack name with len? In this case, the while loop will be executed even if the length is <= 2 or >=18.

Comment: @Zizouz212 But that is when we want the user to enter a different texture pack name, when that condition holds.

Comment: Then you should be using a `try` `except` block then, and raise a `ValueError` when something like that comes up.

Comment: the error should say "Error - texture pack name length should be between 2 and 17 characters" would have changed it myself but my rep sucksXD

Comment: Then instead of raising a ValueError, just raise a string. You can look at my revised answer and if you need more clarification, just leave a comment.